# Error LinAlgError: Schur decomposition solver error en modelo SARIMAX

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de realizar una predicción con una ventana deslizante de una serie temporal en `Python` con `SARIMAX` de un `dataframe` con las siguientes columnas:

```
Index([ 'time', 'total_bases', 'free_bases', 'longitude', 'latitude',
    'dock_bikes', 'station_id', 'fecha', 'day_of_week', 'day', 'month', 
    'hour', 'tmed', 'prec', 'tmin', 'horatmin', 'tmax', 'horatmax', 
    'presMax', 'presMin', 'dock_bikes_yesterday', 'dock_bikes_week_ago', 
    'dock_bikes_2_weeks_ago', 'dock_bikes_3_weeks_ago', 
    'dock_bikes_month_ago', '_time', 'diff_bicis_1', 'diff_bicis_6', 
    'diff_bicis_12', 'diff_bicis_18', 'diff_bicis_24', 'mean_bikes_6' ], 
    dtype = 'object' )
```

La variable sería dock_bikes que es de tipo entero y los datos son con una frecuencia de cada hora

Mi código:

```
def mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)) * 100


# Divide los datos en conjuntos de entrenamiento usando train_test_split

serie_temporal=dfs[['dock_bikes']]
X = np.arange(len(serie_temporal)).reshape(-1, 1)
y = serie_temporal.values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=24, shuffle=False)

#train_data = pd.Series(y_train, index=data.index[:len(y_train)])
#test_data = pd.Series(y_test, index=data.index[len(y_train):]


#train_data = pd.Series(y_train, index=dfs_primer_mes.index[:len(y_train)])
#test_data = pd.Series(y_test, index=dfs_primer_mes.index[len(y_train):])

#train_data = pd.Series(y_train.flatten(), index=dfs_primer_mes.index[:len(y_train)])
#test_data = pd.Series(y_test, index=dfs_primer_mes.index[len(y_train):])

train_data = pd.Series(y_train.reshape(-1), index=dfs.index[:len(y_train)])
test_data = pd.Series(y_test.reshape(-1), index=dfs.index[len(y_train):])


# órdenes p, d, q, P, D, Q y s definidos
p=1
d=0
q=0
P=1
D=1
Q=0
s=24

window_size = 6 # Define el tamaño de la ventana deslizante

# Entrena el modelo SARIMAX con los datos de entrenamiento y ventana deslizante
modelo = SARIMAX(train_data[-window_size:], order=(p, d, q), seasonal_order=(P, D, Q, s), enforce_stationarity=False,verbose=True, enforce_invertibility=False)
resultado = modelo.fit()
# Realiza predicciones recursivas cada 6 horas
num_predicciones = len(test_data) // 6
predicciones = []
for i in range(num_predicciones):
    pred = resultado.get_forecast(steps=6).predicted_mean
    predicciones.extend(pred)
    train_data = train_data.append(test_data.iloc[i * 6: (i * 6) + 6])
    modelo = SARIMAX(train_data[-window_size:], order=(p, d, q), seasonal_order=(P, D, Q, s))
    resultado = modelo.fit()

# Compara las predicciones con los datos reales y verifica si hay overfitting mediante gráficos
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(train_data.index, train_data, label="Datos de entrenamiento")
plt.plot(test_data.index, test_data, label="Datos reales")
plt.plot(test_data.index, predicciones, label="Predicciones")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Calcula el error cuadrático medio (MSE), error absoluto medio (MAE) y error porcentual absoluto medio (MAPE)
mse = mean_squared_error(test_data, predicciones)
mae = mean_absolute_error(test_data, predicciones)
mape = mean_absolute_percentage_error(test_data, predicciones)

print("Error cuadrático medio (MSE):", mse)
print("Error absoluto medio (MAE):", mae)
print("Error porcentual absoluto medio (MAPE):", mape)
```

Para este código me da el siguiente error:

```
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [95], in <cell line: 51>()
     54     train_data = train_data.append(test_data.iloc[i * 6: (i * 6) + 6])
     55     modelo = SARIMAX(train_data[-window_size:], order=(p, d, q), seasonal_order=(P, D, Q, s))
---> 56     resultado = modelo.fit()
     58 # Compara las predicciones con los datos reales y verifica si hay overfitting mediante gráficos
     59 plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\mlemodel.py:704, in MLEModel.fit(self, start_params, transformed, includes_fixed, cov_type, cov_kwds, method, maxiter, full_output, disp, callback, return_params, optim_score, optim_complex_step, optim_hessian, flags, low_memory, **kwargs)
    702         flags['hessian_method'] = optim_hessian
    703     fargs = (flags,)
--> 704     mlefit = super(MLEModel, self).fit(start_params, method=method,
    705                                        fargs=fargs,
    706                                        maxiter=maxiter,
    707                                        full_output=full_output,
    708                                        disp=disp, callback=callback,
    709                                        skip_hessian=True, **kwargs)
    711 # Just return the fitted parameters if requested
    712 if return_params:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py:563, in LikelihoodModel.fit(self, start_params, method, maxiter, full_output, disp, fargs, callback, retall, skip_hessian, **kwargs)
    560     del kwargs["use_t"]
    562 optimizer = Optimizer()
--> 563 xopt, retvals, optim_settings = optimizer._fit(f, score, start_params,
    564                                                fargs, kwargs,
    565                                                hessian=hess,
    566                                                method=method,
    567                                                disp=disp,
    568                                                maxiter=maxiter,
    569                                                callback=callback,
    570                                                retall=retall,
    571                                                full_output=full_output)
    572 # Restore cov_type, cov_kwds and use_t
    573 optim_settings.update(kwds)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\optimizer.py:241, in Optimizer._fit(self, objective, gradient, start_params, fargs, kwargs, hessian, method, maxiter, full_output, disp, callback, retall)
    238     fit_funcs.update(extra_fit_funcs)
    240 func = fit_funcs[method]
--> 241 xopt, retvals = func(objective, gradient, start_params, fargs, kwargs,
    242                      disp=disp, maxiter=maxiter, callback=callback,
    243                      retall=retall, full_output=full_output,
    244                      hess=hessian)
    246 optim_settings = {'optimizer': method, 'start_params': start_params,
    247                   'maxiter': maxiter, 'full_output': full_output,
    248                   'disp': disp, 'fargs': fargs, 'callback': callback,
    249                   'retall': retall, "extra_fit_funcs": extra_fit_funcs}
    250 optim_settings.update(kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\optimizer.py:651, in _fit_lbfgs(f, score, start_params, fargs, kwargs, disp, maxiter, callback, retall, full_output, hess)
    648 elif approx_grad:
    649     func = f
--> 651 retvals = optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b(func, start_params, maxiter=maxiter,
    652                                  callback=callback, args=fargs,
    653                                  bounds=bounds, disp=disp,
    654                                  **extra_kwargs)
    656 if full_output:
    657     xopt, fopt, d = retvals

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\lbfgsb.py:197, in fmin_l_bfgs_b(func, x0, fprime, args, approx_grad, bounds, m, factr, pgtol, epsilon, iprint, maxfun, maxiter, disp, callback, maxls)
    185     disp = iprint
    186 opts = {'disp': disp,
    187         'iprint': iprint,
    188         'maxcor': m,
   (...)
    194         'callback': callback,
    195         'maxls': maxls}
--> 197 res = _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args=args, jac=jac, bounds=bounds,
    198                        **opts)
    199 d = {'grad': res['jac'],
    200      'task': res['message'],
    201      'funcalls': res['nfev'],
    202      'nit': res['nit'],
    203      'warnflag': res['status']}
    204 f = res['fun']

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\lbfgsb.py:360, in _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds, disp, maxcor, ftol, gtol, eps, maxfun, maxiter, iprint, callback, maxls, finite_diff_rel_step, **unknown_options)
    354 task_str = task.tobytes()
    355 if task_str.startswith(b'FG'):
    356     # The minimization routine wants f and g at the current x.
    357     # Note that interruptions due to maxfun are postponed
    358     # until the completion of the current minimization iteration.
    359     # Overwrite f and g:
--> 360     f, g = func_and_grad(x)
    361 elif task_str.startswith(b'NEW_X'):
    362     # new iteration
    363     n_iterations += 1

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py:267, in ScalarFunction.fun_and_grad(self, x)
    265 if not np.array_equal(x, self.x):
    266     self._update_x_impl(x)
--> 267 self._update_fun()
    268 self._update_grad()
    269 return self.f, self.g

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py:233, in ScalarFunction._update_fun(self)
    231 def _update_fun(self):
    232     if not self.f_updated:
--> 233         self._update_fun_impl()
    234         self.f_updated = True

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py:137, in ScalarFunction.__init__.<locals>.update_fun()
    136 def update_fun():
--> 137     self.f = fun_wrapped(self.x)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py:134, in ScalarFunction.__init__.<locals>.fun_wrapped(x)
    130 self.nfev += 1
    131 # Send a copy because the user may overwrite it.
    132 # Overwriting results in undefined behaviour because
    133 # fun(self.x) will change self.x, with the two no longer linked.
--> 134 return fun(np.copy(x), *args)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py:531, in LikelihoodModel.fit.<locals>.f(params, *args)
    530 def f(params, *args):
--> 531     return -self.loglike(params, *args) / nobs

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\mlemodel.py:939, in MLEModel.loglike(self, params, *args, **kwargs)
    936 if complex_step:
    937     kwargs['inversion_method'] = INVERT_UNIVARIATE | SOLVE_LU
--> 939 loglike = self.ssm.loglike(complex_step=complex_step, **kwargs)
    941 # Koopman, Shephard, and Doornik recommend maximizing the average
    942 # likelihood to avoid scale issues, but the averaging is done
    943 # automatically in the base model `fit` method
    944 return loglike

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\kalman_filter.py:983, in KalmanFilter.loglike(self, **kwargs)
    967 r"""
    968 Calculate the loglikelihood associated with the statespace model.
    969 
   (...)
    979     The joint loglikelihood.
    980 """
    981 kwargs.setdefault('conserve_memory',
    982                   MEMORY_CONSERVE ^ MEMORY_NO_LIKELIHOOD)
--> 983 kfilter = self._filter(**kwargs)
    984 loglikelihood_burn = kwargs.get('loglikelihood_burn',
    985                                 self.loglikelihood_burn)
    986 if not (kwargs['conserve_memory'] & MEMORY_NO_LIKELIHOOD):

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\kalman_filter.py:903, in KalmanFilter._filter(self, filter_method, inversion_method, stability_method, conserve_memory, filter_timing, tolerance, loglikelihood_burn, complex_step)
    900 kfilter = self._kalman_filters[prefix]
    902 # Initialize the state
--> 903 self._initialize_state(prefix=prefix, complex_step=complex_step)
    905 # Run the filter
    906 kfilter()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\representation.py:983, in Representation._initialize_state(self, prefix, complex_step)
    981     if not self.initialization.initialized:
    982         raise RuntimeError('Initialization is incomplete.')
--> 983     self._statespaces[prefix].initialize(self.initialization,
    984                                          complex_step=complex_step)
    985 else:
    986     raise RuntimeError('Statespace model not initialized.')

File statsmodels\tsa\statespace\_representation.pyx:1373, in statsmodels.tsa.statespace._representation.dStatespace.initialize()

File statsmodels\tsa\statespace\_representation.pyx:1362, in statsmodels.tsa.statespace._representation.dStatespace.initialize()

File statsmodels\tsa\statespace\_initialization.pyx:288, in statsmodels.tsa.statespace._initialization.dInitialization.initialize()

File statsmodels\tsa\statespace\_initialization.pyx:406, in statsmodels.tsa.statespace._initialization.dInitialization.initialize_stationary_stationary_cov()

File statsmodels\tsa\statespace\_tools.pyx:1284, in statsmodels.tsa.statespace._tools._dsolve_discrete_lyapunov()

LinAlgError: Schur decomposition solver error.
```

Según he visto en otros foros a mi modelo le he añadido:

```
enforce_stationarity=False, enforce_invertibility=False
```

pero con y sin eso me salta el mismo error. Usando

```
initialization='approximate_diffuse'
```

tampoco se resuelve.
Por favor, ¿podrían intentar ayudarme con este error?

Muchas gracias de antemano.